# How do I eliminate white space in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap is inserting a lot of white space between div rows and spans below the App Store button on the following page. I have tried to implement solutions from other threads but non have worked.

How can I change the syntax of the following page to remove the whitespace between the top and bottom of the user testimonial section?

http://vidalingua.com/traducteur-anglais-iphone-ipad.php

One user suggested the following solution on another thread but I don't know where to insert it.

```
.no-padding {
 padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theme.css, change/replace the CSS to the following selector:

```
#testimonials {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

In external-pages.css, change/replace the CSS for the following selector:

```
.features_page .section_header {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```